# laravel 8 multiple user redirect to different pages with auth command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i have 4 types of user which is 'admin', 'staff', 'lecturer', 'student'. i already made that when user login, it will redirect to the dashboard and i want to make the other 3 users to the booking page. supposedly with a simple if-else statement it can be done i believe. but tried doing it, it puts an error.

here are my AdminMiddleware.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->usertype == 'admin')
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/booking')->with('status','you are not allowed to enter uitm dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

and in my logincontroller.php, i do it like this:

```
protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if(Auth::user()->usertype == 'admin')
        {
            return 'dashboard';
        }
        else
        {
            return 'booking';
        }
    }
```

web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function () {

    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    });
});
```

Comment: _it puts an error_ type, location?

Comment: it just go to 404 error page

Comment: First thing, in there the route _booking_ is not defined, another thing to check is what `redirectTo()` needs to return, perhaps it's the name of the route so you'll need to name them.

Comment: so i need to do 3 group for staff, lecturer and students for booking?

Answer (score 0):

The `->name()` at the end of the routes in case your redirect needs a name.
And the first line if you don't have it already. It will be the route for staff, lecturers, and students (admin can access too).

```
Route::get('/booking', /* code */)->name('booking');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});
```